# Should more popular tags in the long term be used in the placeholder text?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the tags placeholder text when writing a new question includes the tag [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump):

[image: tags placeholder text screenshot]

Since Donald Trump is no longer the president of the USA, there are less new questions being posted about him compared to before.

Wouldn’t it be more helpful to new users if the suggested tags are ones that would remain popular in the long term? For example, [international-law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) or [voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting).

Comment: I think the tag suggestions are based on tag usage and that tag still has a lot of use compared to other tags.

Comment: @JoeW Eventually it won't though.

Comment: Which was my point, as fewer people use that tag it will likely change suggested tags.

Comment: As a side note, after this site grows to be large enough, it might possible to request to have suggested tags. See here: [How are “Suggested Tags” chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907) and [Automatically determine tags while writing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13709).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it could be helpful, but I don't think it's something we can change easily. It's not something moderators control. I assume these suggestions are automatically selected based on frequent tag usage, possibly looking at more recent questions as well.

In any case, I don't think it's a bad selection per se. Right now it shows quite some diversity:

- [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) suggests that individual politicians and American politics is on-topic.
- [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) hints at using some locale tag. It also shows that the site is not just about US politics.
- [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) suggests using a tag for a legislature or organization that's relevant to the question.

It could certainly be worse if all three tags were politicians or described different locales.

The suggestion to use conceptual tags only might not be a good idea because we want some current event / politician tags in there as well if they help future visitors find the questions they're looking for.